# How do I make an object perpendicular to a face with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Relevant codepen:

http://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/yNebep

In my game I have a model of an alien tree.
For each face of this tree I generate a pyramid (`CylinderGeometry` with 4 faces), and position it at the center of the face. Then I wish for this pyramid to be perpendicular to the face, so that I'll get a tree with spikes.
I've tried achieving this with `object.lookAt` and point it at the face normal, but weird things happen. For example:

[image]

If I add

`cylinderGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( - Math.PI / 2 ) );`

The shape in the middle works as expected, but the rest is still distorted
[image]

What is the proper way to get my spiked tree?

*Bonus question*

How would I go about merging these spikes to the original geometry after proper creation and orientation so that I don't have so many separate objects?

Comment: I have posted an answer to your main question. Regarding your additional issues, I recommend you try merging yourself, and if you need help, then make a separate post. You may have to read the source code so you understand what is going on behind the scenes in the merge code. It may be more efficient to merge the spikes together as one geometry first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create cylinder and point it in a particular direction. One way to do that is to use the following pattern:

Create the geometry.

```
var cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 1, 10, 25, 4, 1 );
```

Translate the geometry so the base sits at the origin.

```
cylinderGeometry.translate( 0, 12.5, 0 );
```

Rotate the geometry so the top points in the direction of the positive-Z axis.

```
cylinderGeometry.rotateX( Math.PI / 2 );
```

Create the mesh.

```
var cylinder = new THREE.Mesh( cylinderGeometry , characterSkinMaterial );
```

Objects in three.js are by default "looking" in the direction of their local positive-Z axis. (Except the camera, which looks down its negative-Z axis.)

Tell the cylinder to "look" in the direction you want. Since we have transformed the geometry, this will make the top of the cylinder point in the desired direction.

```
cylinder.lookAt( face.normal );
```

Now place the cylinder wherever you want it.

```
cylinder.position.copy( centerPoint );              

obj.add( cylinder );
```

three.js r.91

Comment: I appreciate the response West! Unfortunately even with your suggestion I get the same odd effect: the cylinders on the center shape are aligned correctly, while the rest of the cylinders are not aligned properly to their faces. Here's a codepen with your modified code: http://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/xGZrww I've updated the question with an image that I hope explains better

Comment: You are making mistakes. The code I posted works. I know, because I tried it -- twice now.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I apologize! I've accidently switched the order of the lookAt and position.copy, and sorting that out did the trick. Thank you so much! :)